# how can i see how much memory my app is using out of its VM budget?

Tags: android, memory-management, ddms

I've looked in DDMS but didn't see anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have clicked "Update Heap" button in DDMS in Devices view.

Comment: when i do it only says Heap Size which is only about 3MB or so. I know (depending on hardware) the VM budget is typically 16 or 24 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You see only about 3Mb (which is great btw) because the VM allocates just as much as it needs. If you start loading images in your app you'll see it grow. When it reaches 16 (for 320x480 devices) or 24 (for larger devices) Mb, you'll get an `OutOfMemory` error

Answer (score 1):

sergiu posted some code here: [How do I detect the heap size usage of an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820353/how-do-i-detect-the-heap-size-usage-of-an-android-application)