# How do I detect the heap size usage of an android application

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget

I would like to know the amount of heap space used by my android application in two ways:  - programmatically
 - through DDMS.

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android) post, prior to posting here. In that post, it is mentioned that, `Debug.getNativeHeapSize()` returns the heapsize. Is this the exact method I should use, in order to programmatically detect the heap size? If so, where should I log it in order to get the correct heapsize usage of my application?

Comment: In this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android Dianne provides a ton of information that may help.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

here's what I use:

```
public static void logHeap() {
        Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())/new Double((1048576));
        Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize())/1048576.0;
        Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize())/1048576.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

        Log.d("tag", "debug. =================================");
        Log.d("tag", "debug.heap native: allocated " + df.format(allocated) + "MB of " + df.format(available) + "MB (" + df.format(free) + "MB free)");
        Log.d("tag", "debug.memory: allocated: " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1048576)) + "MB of " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1048576))+ "MB (" + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1048576)) +"MB free)");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Please note that also there are heap view in DDMS and you can use [MAT Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) which is more than helpful especially in memory leaks tracking BUT and this is a huge but the numbers you see are reference only memory that is managed by VM. There are a lot of subsystems in android that are implemented underneath VM - native. The simplest example Bitmap class. You will not see the whole memory allocated to a Bitmap in DDMS and garbage collector is not very good/fast at recovering this memory. so be careful.