# WebView eating up too much memory

Tags: android, android-webview

In my app there are two activities viz A and B.

**Activity A:**

It has a list which displays information about an item briefly. When an item on A is clicked, it loads Activity B.

**Activity B:**

It has two web views and several listviews. Top of the activity is occupied by header web view. Lower part of activity has tab host, this hosts the second web view in first tab and remaining tab each hosts a list view.

**Problem:**

When user navigates from A to B, the heap size increases significantly. Even after I navigate back from B to A, heap size continues to be the same. There is not even a byte decrease, in fact it increases sometimes. Yes its because of these web views. I have read about web view memory leaks on SO and other sites. I followed approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130654/memory-leak-in-webview/8011027#8011027)

1. Added web view dynamically inside a container[RelativeLayout]. Removed webview on activities onDestroy
2. Sub classed web view as suggested in the SO article
3. Cleared web view cache every time etc

No matter what heap size does not come back to what it was before navigating to B.

Really appreciate if someone can guide me to a possible fix

**Note:**

I have already read this and followed this issue on SO. 
[Memory leak in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130654/memory-leak-in-webview/8011027#8011027)

Edit:

I have tried without web views in B and the increase in heap size is very very less around 0.5 MB but with web views it creases by 4-5 MB

Heap size logs ( got by following suggestion mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820353/how-do-i-detect-the-heap-size-usage-of-an-android-application)  )

```
onCreate B
debug.heap native: allocated 4.11MB of 4.17MB (0.01MB free) in []    
debug.memory: allocated: 12.00MB of 96.00MB (1.00MB free)


onDestroy B
debug.heap native: allocated 8.66MB of 10.08MB (0.48MB free) in []    
debug.memory: allocated: 12.00MB of 96.00MB (1.00MB free)

on Resume A    
debug.heap native: allocated 7.94MB of 10.08MB (1.32MB free) in []
debug.memory: allocated: 12.00MB of 96.00MB (0.00MB free)
```

I cross checked the numbers by taking heap dump before and after B is started and destoryed, heap size are quite close to the one I get it in logs

Comment: what is heap size? where do you get numbers?

Comment: Have took heap dumps and used the method suggested in SO. See my edit

Comment: does it cause OOM ? if not, maybe it's just an optimization of some kind? have you tried (for testing) calling GC, in order to see if the heap size goes back to normal? BTW, you don't have to use heap dumps. there is already a button in the DDMS to show the status of the heap (plus you can do it programmatically) .

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I dont get OOM Exception.True. Had taken dump to check memory leak and used the numbers from there. I am calling GC explicitly in onDestroy still there is no effect.

Comment: no don't call it on onDestroy. call it when you really reach the other activity. also, you don't need to call it in code. you can do it via the DDMS. just choose the process of the app, and then choose the green cylinder, and then in the "heap" window view, press on "cause GC" or something. it will show you the current memory usage after the GC . the reason i'm saying to check the heap outside of the activity that was destroyed is that things might still be alive during this method, so it's better to check the status when you are sure it was GC-ed.

Comment: Have tried it, amount of memory reclaimed is very less it ll be around 0.5 MB but as i mentioned in question before B was launched heap size was around 4MB and then with B it goes to around 8 MB. After coming back to A even with GC heap size comes to around 7.5 MB or something. Should not it go back at around 4MB

Comment: @JeeZ: No, the is only guaranteed to free all it can before an OOME. With 7.5MB we are nowhere near such a thing. Even with `System.gc()` it is not guaranteed to collect garbage. Therefore: why should he waste processing time if it's not necessary?

Comment: Did you found an answer? I am facing the same issue right now.

Answer (score 15):

I followed series of steps and got the memory footprint reduced. This is what I did,
instead of creating webview statically via xml I now create webview programmatically and add it to a container. Once webview is no longer needed I remove the webview from the container then I remove all views from webview and call destroy on it. Eventually memory allocated reduces.

```
private void releaseWebView() {

    webViewContainerRelView.removeAllViews();
        if(mWebView != null){
            mWebView.setTag(null);          
            mWebView.clearHistory();
            mWebView.removeAllViews();          
            mWebView.clearView();
            mWebView.destroy();
            mWebView = null;
        }
}
```

I call releaseWebView() from onDetachedFromWindow method of Activity as below.

```
@Override
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    releaseWebViews();
}
```