# webview consumes too much RAM memory?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing an android Reader application., in that i am using web view to load HTML pages. to load an HTML page in the web view take too much ram memory ie around 50-100 mb for a 1 mb html page. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008488/6113352

Comment: Thanks for your replay. actually i am using a single activity page and need to lode around 20 html page in a single web view by left right arrow.