# After how much memory consumption Android throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, out-of-memory

Its an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583292), but still in most of the places i found out that an android app gets around `16-32 MB` memory

But when i check `android Profiler`, it says that my app is currently using around `350 MB` memory on `Samsung Galaxy S7`.

I get `OutOfMemoryException` on my app a couple of times, I was curious why its happening. When i dig down a little i found out about `16-32 MB` limit, but in actual my app is using `350 MB`

I want to know how much memory a normal android phone gives to each app, or is it a variable number, and if no app is running android will not give `outOfMemoryException`, and if so many apps are in stack then there is a higher chance of `OutOfMemoryException`

But again there will be some limits.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675557/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-ram-an-app-can-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices vary significantly now that the OS is getting older. You should definitely aim for under 32mb limit if you want your app to work on lower end devices to be safe. Unless you are loading some very large images it sounds like your code is leaking memory.

Start by removing any image (or other asset) loading from your app to see if you still have problems.
If you do, check out [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), and when you find the leaks learn about them and why they are happening because it will help you immeasurably to become a better Android programmer. One of the chief ways apps leak memory is by passing an Activity context to a long running task :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel :)